# How to get the column name as string in r

Tags: r, string, dataframe, text-parsing

I am struggling with this silly problem to which I can't seem to find a solution

I have a dataframe and i need to get a column name as string.

e.g. out of

```
df$month
```

I would like to get "month". I would need to automate this such that it could be generalized to

```
data$variable
```

and output

```
 "variable"
```

for any dataframe and variable name.

Thanks in advance for this lifesaver

Comment: `colnames(df)` might help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

The question you are asking is a good one, but the answer is way more complicated than it should be.  **The conversion from data names to strings in R is a difficult process that is typically best to avoid.**  However, if you do *really* need to get the name of a dataframe's column as a string, this function will do the job:

```
columnName <- function(ColumnReference) {
  return(substring(deparse(substitute(ColumnReference)),which(strsplit(deparse(substitute(ColumnReference)),"")[[1]]=="$")[1]+1))
}
```

For example:

```
columnName(df$month)
```

Returns:

```
"month"
```

To get `"variable"` from `data$variable`, the process is exactly the same:

```
columnName(data$variable)
```

##### How it works:

`deparse(substitute(ColumnReference))` returns whatever you entered in the parenthesis as a string.  So, if `ColumnReference == df$variable`, this portion of the code will return `"df$variable"`.  Of course, we only want the last part of the string, the part that comes after `"$"`.  So to get a portion of the string, we use the `substring(string, first)` function.  The second parameter in the substring function determines where to start cutting out the substring from the string.  In our case, this is going to be the index of the `"$"` character, plus one so that the `"$"` character is not included in our substring.  A list of where character `x` occurs in string `y` can be obtained with the code `which(strsplit(y, "")[[1]] == x)`.  Since we are only looking for one occurrence of `"$"`, we will add `[1]` to the end of that code.  So the function, in total, is like this:

```
return(
  substring(
    text = input as string,
    first = index of "$" in (input as string)
      + 1
  )
)
```

Here is an organized layout of the function:

```
columnName <- function(ColumnReference) {
  return(
    substring(
      text = deparse(substitute(ColumnReference)),
      first = which(strsplit(deparse(substitute(ColumnReference)),"")[[1]]=="$")[1] + 1
    )
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As `data$var` returns a vector of values, here's a `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  select(variable) %>% 
  colnames()
```

An example:

```
iris %>% 
  select(Species) %>% 
  colnames()
```

Output:

```
[1] "Species"
```